# Javascript boolean true turns false, false does not turn true

Tags: javascript

This looks extremely trivial but I am not sure why it is not working.

I am utilizing div's instead of checkboxes for my web application. I am using a javascript feature called "contentEditable" to set a boolean attribute to an HTML div element.

Below is the code to switch the attribute true or false:

```
$(document).on('click', '.chartPageSensorBox', function () {
    var chartNumber = this.id.charAt(6),
        visibilityIndex = this.id.charAt(9),
        checkBoxToggle = this.id.contentEditable; 

    //the alert below returns default value,  output is: 'true true'
    alert(this.id.contentEditable + " " + checkBoxToggle);

    checkBoxToggle = !checkBoxToggle;

    this.id.contentEditable = checkBoxToggle;

    //the alert output now is: 'false false'
    alert(this.id.contentEditable + " " + checkBoxToggle);

    //The series for the chart successfully turns off because it is false
    allCharts[chartNumber - 1].dyGraph.setVisibility(visibilityIndex, checkBoxToggle);
});
```

Now the issue is, when I click on the div again, false remains false and never turns back to true, which I do not understand why since the if statement should turn checkBoxToggle to true.

EDIT #1: cleaned up the code, but did not fix the error just to make it more legible for future readers.

EDIT #2: Please see code below. The core issue still persists...

```
$(document).on('click', '.chartPageSensorBox', function () {
    var chartNumber = this.id.charAt(6),
        visibilityIndex = this.id.charAt(9),
        checkBoxToggle = $(this).prop("contentEditable");

    alert(checkBoxToggle); 
    checkBoxToggle = !checkBoxToggle;
    alert(checkBoxToggle);

    //After the alerts, true becomes false, but false remains false indefinitely. 

    $(this).prop("contentEditable", checkBoxToggle);

    allCharts[chartNumber - 1].dyGraph.setVisibility(visibilityIndex, checkBoxToggle);
});
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(this.id)`?  Why not just use `this`?

Comment: silly error... good point.

Comment: I am aware. that's what i did initially... I 'expanded' the code to try to debug it.

Comment: @NutellaAddict Try my solution if it works?

Comment: @praveen - taking a look, using the JQuery approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things.

1. Use `this` instead of `document.getElementById(this.id)`.
2. Use `.isContentEditable` instead of `.contentEditable` while checking if it has the property.

   ```
   alert(this.isContentEditable + " " + checkBoxToggle);
   ```
3. Moreover, you need to set the `contentEditable` property using [`"true"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) and not `true`. Not sure why. So try that!

Finally, change the below:

```
if (checkBoxToggle) {
    checkBoxToggle = false;
} else {
    checkBoxToggle = true;
}
```

To:

```
checkBoxToggle = !checkBoxToggle;
```

In simple ways, since you are using `jQuery`, you can just use:

```
$(this).prop("contenteditable");        // Getter
$(this).prop("contenteditable", true);  // Set to true
$(this).prop("contenteditable", false); // Set to false
```

Comment: Praveen is correct, the .contentEditable attribute is a string therefore if(checkBoxToggle) {} will always be true. .isContentEditable returns the boolean so in this case that is the correct answer

Comment: Everything you suggest is only cosmetic. None of the suggestions solve the actual problem.

Comment: @Juhana Please read fully, test it and check. What I have done is tested and proved in Chrome.

Comment: @ praveen, I updated the problem, but the core issue still remains, false does not become true.